# PyQT | Окно поверх других | WindowStaysOnTopHint

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyqt5

**Good afternoon, dear friends!**

Подскажите, пожалуйста ... есть софтинка для работы (шаблонер).
Остался последний штрих .... Необходимо, чтобы программа была поверх других окон. Знаю, что это можно сделать через WindowStaysOnTopHint, но все  попытки НЕ увенчались успехом.

Помогите, пожалуйста ....

```
_____________________desing.py (UI)________________________________
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'design.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(250, 350)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(250, 350))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(250, 350))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("1.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setAccessibleName("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 200, 220, 30))
        self.lineEdit.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.lineEdit.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.lineEdit.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.lineEdit.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.lineEdit.setToolTip("")
        self.lineEdit.setStatusTip("")
        self.lineEdit.setWhatsThis("")
        self.lineEdit.setAccessibleName("")
        self.lineEdit.setAccessibleDescription("")
        self.lineEdit.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(40000)
        self.lineEdit.setFrame(True)
        self.lineEdit.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Normal)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(False)
        self.lineEdit.setCursorMoveStyle(QtCore.Qt.LogicalMoveStyle)
        self.lineEdit.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, 10, 231, 150))
        self.scrollArea.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.scrollArea.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -214, 212, 362))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_1.setEnabled(True)
        self.button_1.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.button_1.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.button_1.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.button_1.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
        self.button_1.setStyleSheet("")
        self.button_1.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.button_1.setObjectName("button_1")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_1)
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_2.setObjectName("button_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_2)
        self.button_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_3.setObjectName("button_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_3)
        self.button_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_4.setObjectName("button_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_4)
        self.button_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_5.setObjectName("button_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_5)
        self.button_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_6.setObjectName("button_6")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_6)
        self.button_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_7.setObjectName("button_7")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_7)
        self.button_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_8.setObjectName("button_8")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_8)
        self.button_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_9.setEnabled(True)
        self.button_9.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.button_9.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.button_9.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.button_9.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
        self.button_9.setStyleSheet("")
        self.button_9.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.button_9.setObjectName("button_9")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_9)
        self.button_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_10.setObjectName("button_10")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_10)
        self.button_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_11.setObjectName("button_11")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_11)
        self.button_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.button_12.setObjectName("button_12")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_12)
        self.formLayout.setLayout(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.verticalLayout)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 240, 190, 100))
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.button_copy = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter)
        self.button_copy.setObjectName("button_copy")
        self.butto_clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter)
        self.butto_clear.setObjectName("butto_clear")
        self.button_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 170, 91, 23))
        self.button_13.setObjectName("button_13")
        self.button_14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_14.setEnabled(True)
        self.button_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 170, 120, 23))
        self.button_14.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.button_14.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.button_14.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.button_14.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
        self.button_14.setStyleSheet("")
        self.button_14.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.button_14.setObjectName("button_14")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.button_copy.clicked.connect(self.lineEdit.copy)
        self.butto_clear.clicked.connect(self.lineEdit.clear)
        self.pushButton.pressed.connect(self.lineEdit.selectAll)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Cool commentary"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите причины..."))
        self.button_1.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.button_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Новорег"))
        self.button_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Старый"))
        self.button_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ИДЕНТ"))
        self.button_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Странные персоданные"))
        self.button_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дробит"))
        self.button_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Опасное направление"))
        self.button_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Странное поведение"))
        self.button_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ошибки 3DS"))
        self.button_9.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.button_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Много карт источников"))
        self.button_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Большой перевод"))
        self.button_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Большие переврды после идента"))
        self.button_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Подбирает сумму"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выделить ВСЁ"))
        self.button_copy.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Копировать"))
        self.butto_clear.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Очистить"))
        self.button_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "НА ИДЕНТ "))
        self.button_14.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.button_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "СЕЛФИ С КАРТОЙ"))
```

И сам MAIN

```
_____________________________main.py_______________________________________
import sys

from design import *  # Импортируем наш интерфейс из файла
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)





        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 1
        self.ui.button_1.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_1)

            # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 2
        self.ui.button_2.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_2)

                # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 3
        self.ui.button_3.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_3)

                # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 4
        self.ui.button_4.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_4)

                # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 5
        self.ui.button_5.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_5)

                   # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 6
        self.ui.button_6.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_6)

                   # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 7
        self.ui.button_7.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_7)

                   # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 8
        self.ui.button_8.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_8)

                   # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 9
        self.ui.button_9.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_9)

                   # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 10
        self.ui.button_10.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_10)

                   # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 11
        self.ui.button_11.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_11)

                   # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 12
        self.ui.button_12.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_12)

                   # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 13
        self.ui.button_13.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_13)

                   # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку 14
        self.ui.button_14.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction_14)




# Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 1
    def MyFunction_1(self):
        a = "Новорег";
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("{}{}".format(self.ui.lineEdit.text(), a))

# Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 2
    def MyFunction_2(self):
        a = "Старый";
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("{}{}".format(self.ui.lineEdit.text(), a))

# Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 3
    def MyFunction_3(self):
        a = "ИДЕНТ";
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("{} | {}".format(self.ui.lineEdit.text(), a))

# Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 4
    def MyFunction_4(self):
        a = "Странные персоданные";
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("{} | {}".format(self.ui.lineEdit.text(), a))

# Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 5
    def MyFunction_5(self):
        a = "Дробит";
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("{} | {}".format(self.ui.lineEdit.text(), a))

# Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 6
    def MyFunction_6(self):
        a = "Опасное направление";
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("{} | {}".format(self.ui.lineEdit.text(), a))

# Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 7
    def MyFunction_7(self):
        a = "Странное поведение";
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("{} | {}".format(self.ui.lineEdit.text(), a))

# Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 8
    def MyFunction_8(self):
        a = "Ошибки 3DS";
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("{} | {}".format(self.ui.lineEdit.text(), a))

# Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 9
    def MyFunction_9(self):
        a = "Много карт источников";
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("{} | {}".format(self.ui.lineEdit.text(), a))

# Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 10
    def MyFunction_10(self):
        a = "Большой перевод";
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("{} | {}".format(self.ui.lineEdit.text(), a))

# Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 11
    def MyFunction_11(self):
        a = "Большие переводы после идента";
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("{} | {}".format(self.ui.lineEdit.text(), a))

# Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 12
    def MyFunction_12(self):
        a = "Подбирает сумму";
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("{} | {}".format(self.ui.lineEdit.text(), a))

# Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 13
    def MyFunction_13(self):
        a = "На идент ID + селфи с картой + ОБОСНОВАНИЕ";
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("{} | {}".format(self.ui.lineEdit.text(), a))

# Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку 14
    def MyFunction_14(self):
        a = "Запрос селфи с картой + ОБОСНОВАНИЕ";
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("{} | {}".format(self.ui.lineEdit.text(), a))


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Не вижу в вашем коде использование WindowStaysOnTopHint

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в `MyWin/__init__` строчку:

```
self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

Этот код добавит флаг `Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint`

---

`QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint`

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста ...Ошибка:     RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type MyWin was never called

Comment: Вы вызываете `QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)`, но у вас класс наследуется от QMainWindow. Лучше используйте новый синтаксис `super().__init__(parent)`

Comment: К сожалению, опять ошибка ............ В 1-м случае: NameError: name 'Qt' is not defined...........................А во втором (новый синтаксис): AttributeError: type object 'QWidget' has no attribute 'super'

Comment: @AlexandrS, первый случай я предусмотрел, поэтому и написал вариант с `QtCore.Qt`. Насчет второго, ошибка странная, вы точно написали так, как я вам написал? :) Посмотрите пример использования `super()` для подобного проекта с UI: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8a4efb58359bf2f97924bc82638cc804af686585/stackoverflow_site__parsing/preparation_description_tag_stackoverflow__qt_gui/mainwindow.py#L29 Должно работать. Но если что, вы можете в том вызове `QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)` поменять QWidget на QMainWindow и должно заработать